# Raid 1, проблемы с загрузкой

Tags: debian, raid

Полетел у меня сегодня утром raid 1 из двух хардов. Дебиан, соответственно все в read-only перемонтировал. Пытался скопировать данные с массива через фтп, забил, ибо не работает в read-only (баг старой версии, надо давно было обновиться).

Вытащил 1 хард, подсунул в тестовый стенд, ФС=RAW, Использовано 100% из 100%. Примонтировать rw ext4 не получается.

Подсунул хард обратно в машину:

> MBR error 1

Я многого не знаю в этой жизни, направьте куда-нибудь. Данные важные.

Comment: А второй хард монтируется на тестовом стенде? И вы осторожнее там, если диск начал физически сыпаться, лучше не особенно трогать его. Может, попробовать сделать с них dd, пока не поздно?

Comment: @T. Fosteman, уточните - как именно RAID у вас собран? Программный, через mdadm, или аппаратный, на внешнем контроллере, или полуаппаратный, он же "fake RAID"?

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, что и второй винчестер у вас выходит (вышел) из строя.

если raid-массив создавался «по-человечески», программой *mdadm*, то и при подключении винчестера к (любым) другим компьютерам информацию можно будет хотя бы скопировать: если он ещё читабелен, то достаточно просто программы `cp` (копировать лучше весь диск/раздел, а не отдельные файлы: `cp /dev/диск /путь/к/сохраняемому/образу`), если читабелен лишь частично, то для спасения хотя бы части информации надо использовать что-нибудь типа [*gnu/ddrescue*](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/).

если же для создания raid-массива использовалось проприетарное «железное» «решение» с помощью контроллера (возможно, интегрированного в материнскую плату), то, вполне возможно, что **даже для чтения** потребуется аналогичный контроллер/плата. что, похоже, у вас и наблюдается.